# @font-face is not working - same code but different hosting

Tags: html, css

Eurostile is the font name which works file in test account but not working in the utadv.com

please check and advise.

[[http://test.3wbiz.com/unlimitedteams/homepage.php]](http://test.3wbiz.com/unlimitedteams/homepage.php%5d)

[[http://www.utadv.com/homepage.php]](http://www.utadv.com/homepage.php%5d)

Answer (score 1):

The font is not uploaded, is not uploaded to the right folder or your CSS is pointing to the wrong folder.

http://www.utadv.com/css/Eurostile-Bold.woff returns a 404 and that's where it's looking for the font file.